# Maybe I've lost the plot, but why is this small piece of JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a generic error handler for my forms

```
var errorsBox = function() {
    var $errorBox = $('#form-error');

    return {
        add: function(errors) {
            if ($errorBox.length === 0) {
                $errorBox = $('<div id="form-error"><ul></ul></div>').appendTo('form');
            };

            $errorBox.find('ul > li').remove();

            $.each(errors, function(i, error) {
                $errorBox.find('ul').append('<li>' + error + '</li>');
            });
        }
    };
};
```

You can play with it on [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/aloya4/edit).

I'm getting

> errorsBox.add is not a function

I'm sure it's really obvious, but I can't seem to understand why this might not be working.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined `errorsBox` to be a function. So, you'd call it likewise:

```
errorsBox().add(...)
```

Comment: It happens to all of us at some time or the other I guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

errorsBox is a function that returns an object.  That returned object has an add() function.

You could do:

```
errorsBox().add(['error1', 'error2']);
```

but it looks a bit strange.  Maybe you're not setting it up quite the way you want.

If you want to be able to call it the way you have it (`errorsBox.add(...)`), then try this:

```
var errorsBox = {
       $errorBox: ('#form-error'),

        add: function(errors) {

            if ($errorBox.length === 0) {
                $errorBox = $('<div id="form-error"><ul></ul></div>').appendTo('form');
            };

            $errorBox.find('ul > li').remove();

            $.each(errors, function(i, error) {

                $errorBox.find('ul').append('<li>' + error + '</li>');

            });
        }
};
```

Comment: BTW, If I was going to use an object literal, I'd need to use `this.$errorBox` to access that variable wouldn't I?